# Problem on installing teamviewer on 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, remote-desktop, teamviewer

I have a problem on installing `teamviewer` on 16.04 LTS. I don't know if this problem is just on my PC but I can't install it.

I found this solution:

> Download the official image from http://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux.aspx (always get 32bit)
>
> Open a console:
>
> ```
> cd ~/Downloads/
> sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_linux.deb
> sudo apt-get -f install  # to install any missing dependencies
> ```
>
> Follow whatever steps it needs you to take.

But it doesn't work...

I also tried this:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gdebi
wget http://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_i386.deb
sudo gdebi teamviewer_linux.deb
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386
```

But this is not working too.

Can anyone help me to install `teamviewer`, please?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "it doesn't work"? What specific error(s) are you seeing, and at what steps of the process?

Comment: Also, this tutorial might be of interest: http://www.ubuntumaniac.com/2015/12/install-teamviewer-11-on-ubuntu-1604.html

Comment: i used those commands and they didn't helped me.

Comment: For anyone to help you, you will need to be WAY more specific. What exact commands did you try, and what exact error(s) did they produce, if any? What do you mean by "it doesn't work" and "they didn't helped me"?

Comment: the problem is that it is installed but it doesn't start. when i click on the teamviewer icon, it shows up just for some seconds and it disappear. so the problem is that it doesn't start. sorry but i'm not so good in english and i can't explain it very good. i hope you understand me now.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, that is much more clear. Could you try starting Teamviewer in a terminal, so you can see what errors it makes? Try typing `teamviewer` in gnome-terminal or another terminal program.

Comment: ok thnx fpr your response. when i type <i>teamviewer</i> in terminal, these lines are showing:

Init...
XRandRWait: No value set. Using default.
XRandRWait: Started by user.
Checking setup...
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/user/.local/share/teamviewer11/dosdevices’: Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/user/.local/share/teamviewer11/.tweak’: Permission denied
wine: /home/user/.local/share/teamviewer11 is not owned by you
wine: /home/user/.local/share/teamviewer11 is not owned by you

Comment: Thank you. Could you please run `sudo chown -R genci /home/genci/.local/share/teamviewer11` in a terminal, and then try running `teamviewer` in a terminal again.

Comment: woow now it works. thank you very much @NickWeinberg. but what was the problem? can you tell us a clear version on how to install teamviewer on 16.04?

Comment: I'm glad it's working! It sounds like the installer just didn't set the ownership of that directory properly. The command `sudo chown -R genci /home/genci/.local/share/teamviewer11` tells Ubuntu that you own that directory, and it's ok for teamviewer to make changes to it. I don't know exactly what you tried, but in the future I would install the .deb file and then run that "chown" command.

Comment: ok thank you @NickWeinberg. this was very helpful...

Comment: This site worked well for me it contains a detailed explanation. https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-teamviewer-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Answer (score 6):

Using `sudo apt-get -f install` or `gdebi` may not always solve dependency problem. Instead, run the following command to install all Teamviewer dependencies.

```
sudo apt-get install libdbus-1-3:i386 libasound2:i386 libexpat1:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libjpeg62:i386 libpng12-0:i386 libsm6:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386 libxinerama1:i386 libxrandr2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxtst6:i386 zlib1g:i386 libc6:i386
```

And then you can install teamview with `dpkg`

```
sudo dpkg -i teamviewer*.deb
```

Source: https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/install-teamviewer-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus

Comment: E: Package 'libpng12-0:i386' has no installation candidate.

Answer (score 1):

At this time 2018-08-12 the latest TeamViewer for Linux, the version 13

[image: TeamViewer 13 for Linux]

not working fine to Remote Control it from a [Android Phone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.teamviewer.market.mobile)

The solution are uninstall version 13 and install the previus version from here:

**TeamViewer 12**

[https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/previous-versions/](https://www.teamviewer.com/download/previous-versions/)

[image]

You can use gdebi to do that (use it from GUI, no command line need), just right clic over .deb file and select uninstall version 13, and next close and right clic in version 12 and install it

Answer (score 0):

On your, perhaps fresh installed, ubuntu 16 machine you need to install from the terminal the following libraries...

```
sudo apt-get install libdbus-1-3:i386 libasound2:i386 libexpat1:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libfreetype6:i386 libpng12-0:i386 libsm6:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxfixes3:i386 zlib1g:i386 libice6:i386 libuuid1:i386 libsystemd0:i386 libgcrypt20:i386 libselinux1:i386 libgpg-error0:i386  libpcre3:i386 liblzma5:i386
```

download teamviewer from https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/
then from the terminal go to download folder

```
cd ~/Downloads/
```

and run

```
sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_11.0.57095_i386.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

This discussion may be dead, but in the second attempt of installing team viewer, you typed `sudo gdebi teamviewer_linux.deb`. You need to type the name of the matching version you chose to install. In this case, it should be

```
sudo gdebi teamviewer_i386.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

For my installation, first run

```
sudo apt install ./teamviewer_14.1.18533_amd64.deb
```

It will throw error as 'unmet dependencies' related to qt,then need to run

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

It will install all the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Download `teamviewer*.deb` from TeamViewer official site and Just run the following command:

```
sudo apt install -y ./teamviewer*.deb
```

Answer (score -3):

Please try and download the new TeamViewer `.deb` file from [here](https://downloadap1.teamviewer.com/download/version_11x/teamviewer_11.0.57095_i386.deb) and try and install it:

```
sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_11.0.57095_i386.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: OP says they did that in the first part of the question and it didn't work.