# I can't install Teamviewer 12 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I have tried everything from this question [Problem on installing teamviewer on 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766533/problem-on-installing-teamviewer-on-16-04-lts) but it still doesn't install.

```
$ sudo dpkg -i /home/will/Downloads/teamviewer_12.0.76279_i386.deb
(Reading database ... 229286 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../teamviewer_12.0.76279_i386.deb ...
Unpacking teamviewer:i386 (12.0.76279) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from '/home/will/Downloads/teamviewer_12.0.76279_i386.deb' to decompressor pipe: unexpected end of file or stream
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: internal bzip2 read error: 'UNEXPECTED_EOF'
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /home/will/Downloads/teamviewer_12.0.76279_i386.deb (--install):
 cannot copy extracted data for './opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/wine/lib/wine/winex11.drv.so' to '/opt/teamviewer/tv_bin/wine/lib/wine/winex11.drv.so.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /home/will/Downloads/teamviewer_12.0.76279_i386.deb
```

Comment: unexpected EOF means, the file is smaller than it should be. Try redownloading.

Comment: Ok, in the morning (it's  10:30 PM here in Australia) i'll try t redownload it and see if that works

Comment: @davidbaumann It worked, that's a weird kinda bug, dunno why the file was smaller than it was meant to be, thanks nonetheless.

Comment: I will write this as an answer, so you can mark your problem as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message

```
internal bzip2 read error: 'UNEXPECTED_EOF'
```

means that the file is smaller than expected. In your case, I assume your download is broken.

There are multiple reasons for this to happen, but I just recommend to download again later.